# BeginInvoke из другого потока сильно тормозит и вешает намертво ГУИ

Tags: c#, winforms, tpl

Есть сторонний класс TelnetClient. С помощью него я по нажатию кнопки устанавливаю соединение, и подписываюсь на входящие сообщения. По нажатию другой кнопки отправляю команду на чтение удаленного каталога. Исходники стороннего класса доступны, он основан на TPL, и `HandleMessageReceived` вызывается не из ГУИ-потока, поэтому я вынужден использовать (Begin)Invoke

```
TelnetClient tc = null;
private async void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tc = new TelnetClient("host", 23, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 
        new System.Threading.CancellationToken());            
    tc.MessageReceived += HandleMessageReceived;       
    await tc.Connect();
    await tc.Send("username");
    await tc.Send("password");
}

private void HandleMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs mea)
{        
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            textBox1.Text += mea.Message;                
        }));
}     

private async void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await tc?.Send("dir");
}
```

Код работает, но плохо:

1) Выполняется излишне долго (несколько минут). Любым нормальным telnet приложением на этом же хосте команда `dir` выполняется в разы быстрее (около секунды).

2) Блокирует ГУИ.

Вопросы

1) Почему блокируется ГУИ? Как избежать?

2) С чем может быть связана низкая производительность? Как избежать?

Comment: Может, у вас миллионы сообщений в секунду?

Comment: попробуйте сделать тоже самое в консоли и посмотрите на производительность. Это позволит исключить возможные тормоза форм, если они имеют место быть. Криминала особенного в коде не вижу, так что нужно как-то локализовать проблему

Comment: @rdorn Да! На консоле не тупит - около секунды.

Comment: @VladD 20888 раз вызывается HandleMessageReceived в ответ на `dir`, в Debug mode из Visual Studio это затягивается на много минут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

20K вызовов — это очень много. UI просто не успевает принимать ваши сообщения.

Делайте по-другому. Если у вашего `TelnetClient` есть API со `Stream`'ом ([как в `TcpClient`'е](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx)), используйте его и читайте построчно.

Если нет — буферизуйте строки в `HandleMessageReceived` до какого-нибудь приличного размера, и отправляйте в UI-при достижении предела или через какое-то разумное время (не меньше десятой доли секунды).

Если вы случайно пользуетесь Reactive Extension'ами, то это великолепная цель для их применения (управление backpressure):

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<MessageReceived>(tc, "MessageReceived")
          .Select(mea => mea.Message)
          .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
          .Where(list => list.Count > 0)
          .Select(list => string.Concat(list))
          .ObserveOn(mainSynchronizationContext)
          .Subscribe(s => textBox1.Text += s);
```

Answer (score 1):

А если вы в файл писать будете, то тоже так делать? А если при этом потоков много сразу?
"Процесс не может получить..." - придется выучить наизусть ^^

Надо сделать очередь с обрабатывающим ее одним отдельным потоком writer, соблюдающим заданный интервал, чтобы и обновлялось достаточно быстро и GUI не вешался.
И эту архитектуру копировать из проекта в проект. Даже если пока вроде бы и не надо.
Я ее делаю сам, но можно поискать что-то готовое, выше вот упомянули про Reactive.